# How do I install OpenCV 4.7.0 with CUDA support in a Conda environment on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: opencv, conda, ubuntu-22.04

I have a Conda environment called "mainenv" set up, and I'm trying to install OpenCV with GPU support inside it. My system is one with Ubuntu 22.04, an AMD 7800x3D CPU, an Nvidia RTX 4090 GPU, and I've installed CUDA 12.1 and CuDNN 8.9. I've been trying to follow the instructions on this site:

https://gist.github.com/raulqf/f42c718a658cddc16f9df07ecc627be7

I've gotten to the point where I run cmake with the following options:

```
cmake 
-D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
-D WITH_TBB=ON -D ENABLE_FAST_MATH=1 \
-D CUDA_FAST_MATH=1 -D WITH_CUBLAS=1 \
-D WITH_CUDA=ON \
-D BUILD_opencv_cudacodec=OFF \
-D WITH_CUDNN=ON \
-D OPENCV_DNN_CUDA=ON \
-D CUDA_ARCH_BIN=8.9 \
-D WITH_V4L=ON -D WITH_QT=OFF \
-D WITH_OPENGL=ON \
-D WITH_GSTREAMER=ON \
-D OPENCV_GENERATE_PKGCONFIG=ON \
-D OPENCV_PC_FILE_NAME=opencv.pc \
-D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON \
-D OPENCV_PYTHON3_INSTALL_PATH=$(python3 -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print(get_python_lib())") \
-D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=$(which python3) \
-D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/Downloads/opencv_contrib-4.7.0/modules \
-D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=OFF -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
-D BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF \
-D CUDNN_LIBRARY=/home/(my username)/anaconda3/envs/mainenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nvidia/cudnn/lib/libcudnn.so.8 \
-D CUDNN_INCLUDE_DIR=/home/(my username)/anaconda3/envs/mainenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nvidia/cudnn/include \
-D CUDNN_VERSION='8.9' ..
```

And the configuration summary implies that it's been built properly. Yet when I try to compile it, I get the following errors:

```
[  3%] Building CXX object modules/sfm/src/libmv/libmv/multiview/CMakeFiles/multiview.dir/fundamental_kernel.cc.o
In file included from /usr/include/string.h:535,
                 from /home/dehavenm/Downloads/opencv-4.7.0/3rdparty/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/stubs/port.h:39,
                 from /home/dehavenm/Downloads/opencv-4.7.0/3rdparty/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/stubs/common.h:48,
                 from /home/dehavenm/Downloads/opencv-4.7.0/3rdparty/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/message_lite.h:45,
                 from /home/dehavenm/Downloads/opencv-4.7.0/3rdparty/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/message_lite.cc:36:
In function ‘void* memcpy(void*, const void*, size_t)’,
    inlined from ‘uint8_t* google::protobuf::io::EpsCopyOutputStream::WriteRaw(const void*, int, uint8_t*)’ at /home/dehavenm/Downloads/opencv-4.7.0/3rdparty/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/io/coded_stream.h:706:16,
    inlined from ‘virtual uint8_t* google::protobuf::internal::ImplicitWeakMessage::_InternalSerialize(uint8_t*, google::protobuf::io::EpsCopyOutputStream*) const’ at /home/dehavenm/Downloads/opencv-4.7.0/3rdparty/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/implicit_weak_message.h:84:28,
    inlined from ‘bool google::protobuf::MessageLite::SerializePartialToZeroCopyStream(google::protobuf::io::ZeroCopyOutputStream*) const’ at /home/dehavenm/Downloads/opencv-4.7.0/3rdparty/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/message_lite.cc:412:30,
    inlined from ‘bool google::protobuf::MessageLite::SerializeToZeroCopyStream(google::protobuf::io::ZeroCopyOutputStream*) const’ at /home/dehavenm/Downloads/opencv-4.7.0/3rdparty/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/message_lite.cc:396:42:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29:33: warning: ‘void* __builtin___memcpy_chk(void*, const void*, long unsigned int, long unsigned int)’ specified size between 18446744071562067968 and 18446744073709551615 exceeds maximum object size 9223372036854775807 [-Wstringop-overflow=]
   29 |   return __builtin___memcpy_chk (__dest, __src, __len,
      |          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   30 |                                  __glibc_objsize0 (__dest));
      |                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In function ‘void* memcpy(void*, const void*, size_t)’,
    inlined from ‘uint8_t* google::protobuf::io::EpsCopyOutputStream::WriteRaw(const void*, int, uint8_t*)’ at /home/dehavenm/Downloads/opencv-4.7.0/3rdparty/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/io/coded_stream.h:706:16,
    inlined from ‘virtual uint8_t* google::protobuf::internal::ImplicitWeakMessage::_InternalSerialize(uint8_t*, google::protobuf::io::EpsCopyOutputStream*) const’ at /home/dehavenm/Downloads/opencv-4.7.0/3rdparty/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/implicit_weak_message.h:84:28,
    inlined from ‘bool google::protobuf::MessageLite::SerializePartialToZeroCopyStream(google::protobuf::io::ZeroCopyOutputStream*) const’ at /home/dehavenm/Downloads/opencv-4.7.0/3rdparty/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/message_lite.cc:412:30:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29:33: warning: ‘void* __builtin___memcpy_chk(void*, const void*, long unsigned int, long unsigned int)’ specified size between 18446744071562067968 and 18446744073709551615 exceeds maximum object size 9223372036854775807 [-Wstringop-overflow=]
   29 |   return __builtin___memcpy_chk (__dest, __src, __len,
      |          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   30 |                                  __glibc_objsize0 (__dest));
      |                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[  3%] Linking CXX static library 3rdparty/lib/libade.a
[  3%] Built target ade
[  3%] Building C object 3rdparty/ippiw/CMakeFiles/ippiw.dir/src/iw_image_op_swap_channels.c.o
```

```
[  8%] Linking CXX static library ../lib/libIlmImf.a
[  8%] Built target IlmImf
[  8%] Linking CXX static library ../lib/liblibprotobuf.a
[  8%] Built target libprotobuf
[  8%] Linking CXX static library ../../../../../../lib/libmultiview.a
[  8%] Built target multiview
make: *** [Makefile:166: all] Error 2
```

I've plugged the error into Google, and I haven't found anything helpful. Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong here? Thank you.